# What is a color ramp?

Tags: node-editor

Can someone explain to me what this is, how it works, and some practical uses for it? I have looked everywhere online and haven't found anything useful. Just wanna know if it's useful or not.

Comment: See http://blender-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/compositing/types/converter/color_ramp.html. Practical usage - nearly everywhere. Yes, it is useful. As your question seems too broad clarify what exactly do you want to know about ColorRamp node.

Comment: ***"I have looked everywhere"***... right... Here are a few examples https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=color+ramp

Answer (score 4):

A Color Ramp is used for many different things. You will use it all the time.

Here are a few examples.

It can be used to mix many different colors.

[image]

It can be used to control how much of a texture you see ie Roughness (and other inputs by clamping the white and blacks).

[image]
[image]

It can also be used as a mask to mix two materials together. By clamping down how much falloff or fade you want your texture/mask to have.

There are more use cases but here are some to get you started.

[image]